# Verify text field not empty using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Suppose I want to verify that a text input field with the ID of "text_input" is not empty (contains text) before continuing to click on a submit button, such as:

```
// verify that html element id "text_input" is not null

var button_Save = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("submit"));
button_Save.Click();
```

How could one go about this?

The HTML for the element I want to verify is not null is:

```
<input name="text_input" value="Fred" id="text_input" tabindex="6" class="label" type="text">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not null"? Did you mean element exists?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it is not empty, that there is text in it

Comment: <input name="text_input" value="Fred" id="text_input" tabindex="6" class="label" type="text">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an input like this:

```
<input name="text_input" value="Fred" id="text_input" tabindex="6" class="label" type="text">
```

Then you can use `element.GetAttribute("value")` to get its value. Source [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.cs#373).

```
var text_input = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("text_input"));
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text_input.GetAttribute("value"))) {
    var button_Save = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("submit"));
    button_Save.Click();
} else {
    // if you want to do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. What purpose does the "!" at the start of the if condition serve?